React Native Conditional Rendering - continuously re-renders
I'm trying to display one template or another based on clicking a button. The "One-Time" template is selected by default. I'm using a boolean and a callback function to flip the boolean value. I've copied functional code from another area of my app to do this but it the computer is saying that the templates are rendering too many times. It isn't working and it's boggling my mind as to what I'm doing wrong.
Below is my code:
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {Alert, Button, Image, Modal, StyleSheet, Text, Pressable, View, TextInput, TouchableHighlight} from 'react-native';

export default function TabTwoScreen() {

  const [showOneTime, setShowOneTime] = useState(true);

  const showTemplate = (template: string) => {
    if(template == 'OneTime')
      setShowOneTime(true);
    else
      setShowOneTime(false);
  }

  const renderOneTimeTemplate = () => {
    return (
      <View>
        <View>
          <Button onPress={showTemplate("OneTime")} title='One-Time' />
          <Button onPress={showTemplate("Recurring")} title='Recurring' />
        </View>

        <Text>OneTime Template</Text>
         
      </View>
    );
  }

  const renderRecurringTemplate = () => {
    return (
      <View>
        <View>
          <Button onPress={showTemplate("OneTime")} title='One-Time' />
          <Button onPress={showTemplate("Recurring")} title='Recurring' />
        </View>
        
        <Text>Recurring Template</Text>

      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    (showOneTime && renderOneTimeTemplate()) ||
    (!showOneTime && renderRecurringTemplate())
  );

}

Thanks for your help.

onPress={showTemplate("OneTime")} -> onPress={() => showTemplate("OneTime")}

The former calls the function and passes it's return value to onPress. The latter passes a callback function that will be called when the button is pressed.

@super Outstanding. It works.

Does this answer your question? React Native onPress being called automatically
